# There are multiple InputBase components inside a > FormControl

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I've an issue :

> Material-UI: There are multiple InputBase components inside a
> FormControl. This is not supported. It might cause infinite rendering
> loops. Only use one InputBase.

I understand what that's mean, but I really need the two input in my form :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import {Button, FilledInput} from "@material-ui/core";

export interface InputValues {
    input1?: string;
    input2?: string;
}

export interface InputProps {
    value: InputValues;
}

export const Input = ({value}: InputProps) => {
    return <div>
        <DependenciesExpressionRow value={value.input1 || ""}/>
        <DependenciesExpressionRow value={value.input2 || ""}/>
        <Button>
        </Button>
    </div>;
};

export interface RowProps {
    value: string;
}

const DependenciesExpressionRow = ({value}: RowProps) => {
    return <div>
        <FilledInput key={value} value={value} multiline rows={5} fullWidth/>
        <Button>

        </Button>
    </div>;
};
```

I called it in :

```
<FormControl>
    <Input value={{input1: expression1Field.value, input2: expression2Field.value}}/>
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this might not seem a good answer. However, the docs and the the raised issue on github have no clear guide!! My workaround was simply just wrap the input element with a `<FormControl />` component. it has stopped the warning without any side-effect. Please keep in mind that my form components are all controlled via `Reactjs` state and hence, i see no problem with this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue but by just wrapping my TextField (in my case) component with FormGroup the message has gone.

```
<FormGroup>
        <TextField
        label="Add new node"
        value={newNode}
        onChange={this.onTextUpdate} />
</FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the reason why: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/16907#issuecomment-518990400

And the answer is to just ***wrap the components with FormControl*** or just ***replace the div with FromControl***.