# Multiple InputBase fields sharing a single InputLabel using FormControl: How (without warning)

Tags: reactjs, forms, material-ui

I'm building a custom form widget where multiple fields need to share a single label.  I need the label to highlight when any of the fields are focused.

Here's a **[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-inputbase-that-share-a-single-inputlabel-unojwj?file=/demo.tsx)**, or if you prefer, here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```js
const MyInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  "label + &": {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
  },
  "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === "light" ? "#fcfcfb" : "#2b2b2b",
    border: "1px solid #ced4da",
    padding: "10px 12px",
    "&:focus": {
      backgroundColor: "rgba(63, 127, 63, 0.1)"
    }
  }
}));

const MyInputLabel = styled(InputLabel)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&.Mui-focused": {
    color: "rgb(63, 175, 63)"
  }
}));

const MyAdornment = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  return (
    <InputAdornment position={"start"}>
      <Typography
        sx={{
          fontSize: "12px",
          color: "rgb(83, 127, 83)"
        }}
      >
        {children}
      </Typography>
    </InputAdornment>
  );
};

export default function InputsThatShareALabel() {
  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate>
      <FormControl variant="standard">
        <MyInputLabel shrink>Medalists</MyInputLabel>
        <MyInputBase startAdornment={<MyAdornment>1ST</MyAdornment>} />
        <MyInputBase startAdornment={<MyAdornment>2ND</MyAdornment>} />
        <MyInputBase startAdornment={<MyAdornment>3RD</MyAdornment>} />
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Everything works as intended but I have the error:

```
There are multiple `InputBase` components inside a FormControl.
This creates visual inconsistencies, only use one `InputBase`.
```

I understand the rationale behind the error, and that [this is not the intended usage of FormControl](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/12197#issuecomment-713410828).  I have read [this related Github issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/16907#issuecomment-518990400) and [this related Github issue](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/22535), etc.  I think the difference is that I'm manually managing the differences in appearance for each field in the group, so I'm not depending on FormControl for that, just taking advantage of the InputLabel's already extant highlight/focus context usage.

I've also taken a look at [this similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65395896/there-are-multiple-inputbase-components-inside-a-formcontrol), but it doesn't seem to quite address my concern.

I think what MUI refers to as "visual inconsistencies" is actually my desired behavior.  I have handrolled my own label-highlighting logic for now, but was wondering if a MUI "way" has emerged to allow this without a warning.